# Can't add bootstrap.min.js within laravel mix

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-mix

I'm trying to combine all of my assets files via `Laravel mix`.

I fall in problem when I tried to add bootstrap js in the mix, it said  `can't resolve propper.js`, but I already add that before it,

Here is my mix configuration code.

```
var mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix
    .js([
        'resources/assets/js/jquery.min.js',
        'resources/assets/js/popper.min.js',
        'resources/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js',
        'resources/assets/js/app.js'
    ], 'public/js/app.js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

[image]

> I think I'm doing something in a wrong way, plz make me correct.

Comment: you need to add popper.js i guess you are using bs4??

Comment: @Mr.Pyramid Yes, I'm using bootstrap 4. I already add `propper.min.js` before `bootstrap.min.js`   https://image.prntscr.com/image/8Nm0NgDUSVGFBhoHeuZLVg.png

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I made it differently a bit. 
I downloaded bootstrap using yarn (or you can use npm). As a result you will have a folder `node_modules/bootstrap`

In the webpack.mix.js I have only `app.js`.

In the app.js I have

```
window.Popper = require('popper.js');

/**
 * We'll load jQuery and the Bootstrap jQuery plugin which provides support
 * for JavaScript based Bootstrap features such as modals and tabs. This
 * code may be modified to fit the specific needs of your application.
 */

window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

require('bootstrap');
```

Note! popper.js and jQuery I also downloaded via yarn (or npm)

Comment: Thank you for this solution.

One issue now is that popper.js has been deprecated. Version 2 (@popperjs/core) does work in the solution. 

Any idea how it can be configured?